# Why does Next.js 14 fail to resolve page route paths?

Tags: css, routes, tailwind-css, router, next.js13

I'm encountering an issue with my Next.js project where I'm receiving the error message: "You cannot have two parallel pages that resolve to the same path." It specifically references /(landing)/page and /(main)/(routes)/(documents)/page. I've checked the route group documentation provided by Next.js, but I'm still unclear on how to resolve this issue effectively. Could you please provide guidance on how to address this error and ensure proper routing in my Next.js application?

[image]

I attempted to define routes in Next.js 14 but encountered unresolved paths for pages. I expected the routes to map correctly to their respective pages, but actual results showed unresolved paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [route groups](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups), aka the folders with `(...)` are not taken into consideration when resolving path, `app/(landing)/page.js` and `app/(main)/(routes)/(documents)/page.js` will match `/` as it's like you had tow `app/page.js`, creating a conflict.

So you have to decide which one should render when `/` is requested. If it's `app/(landing)/page.js`, you should change `app/(main)/(routes)/(documents)/page.js` to something like `app/(main)/(routes)/(documents)/about/page.js`, so it matches `/about`.